# React param routing with Sidebar Component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I've a routing section with two containers. One is login container containing login and Sign up pages while other one has the other routes. Have a look here:
Default container has a FloatCart component which acts as some kind of side component. Clicking on FloatCart leads to a new route 'Checkout'. It works fine as long as there's no route with params. But whenever, I try to move from Product Details page, URL changes to 'product/checkout'. How do I get rid of this? I merely want to route to 'checkout'

I've tried moving Product Details page up to hierarchy but it doesn't work either.

```
const DefaultContainer = () => (
  <div>
    <FloatCart />
    <Route exact path="/menu" component={Menu} />
    <Route exact path="/product/:id" component={ProductDetails} />
    <Route exact path="/checkout" component={CheckoutInfo} />
    <Route exact path="/order-details" component={ConfirmOrder} />
    <Route exact path="/payment" component={Payment} />
    <Route exact path="/order-placed" component={Success} />
  </div>
);
```

This is my routing section:

```
            <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LoginContainer} />
            <Route exact path="/login" component={LoginContainer} />
            <Elements>
            <Route component={DefaultContainer} />
            </Elements>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
```

Edit:
That's the code I use to push to another route:
`this.props.history.push('./checkout');`

Comment: I suppose that the code that is responsible to Going to the Checkout page is inside FloatCart, Can you include that snippest of code please, as an edit to your question, metion me in a comment here afterwards.

Comment: @SultanH.I've added to the post. It's just history.push though

Comment: Can you try it as `this.props.history.push('/checkout')` -without the `.` before the slash.

Comment: Wow. It actually worked. What could be the reason? @SultanH.

Comment: Possibly, `.` will refer to the current path, which is in your case `/product/:id`, and will then push the new path to the latter of the pathname, `/product/checkout` as a replacement to the `id`.

Comment: I understand. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome Usman!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix with:

`this.props.history.push('/checkout')` instead of: `this.props.history.push('/.checkout')`